# Кто (какая программа) исполняет работу самого компилятора?

Tags: компиляция, компилятор, информатика

Если компилятор - это программа осуществляющая трансляцию кода в байт-код или машинный код, то какая программа реализует выполнение этой программы(т.е. самого компилятора)? Есть предположение, что есть компилятор, написанный на машинном коде, и все компиляторы, которые написаны на языках программирования, компилируются компиляторами этих языков, а компиляторы этих языков компилируются еще более низкоуровневыми компиляторами. Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Т.е. как скомпилировали первый компилятор?

Comment: Выглядит так, что вам нужны курсы лекций по "архитектуре ЭВМ", в двух словах это рассказать, укладываясь в формат сайта и его миссию - сложновато. Почитайте классика [Архитектура компьютера, Таненбаум Э.С](https://obuchalka.org/2012021663508/arhitektura-komputera-tanenbaum-e-s-2007.html)

Comment: А я бы рекомендовал начать с https://habr.com/ru/post/68365/

Comment: EOF, да, можно так сказать

Comment: @mrEvgenX, Dmitriy Novikov, спасибо почитаю

Comment: Если совсем топорно и на пальцах рассказывать, то все шло по пути усложнения от простого. Сначала писали прямо в машинных кодах и прямо физически загоняли в микросхему. Потом придумали ассемблер, как человеко-читаемое выражение машинных кодов. Потом придумали язык на один уровень абстракции выше и написали компилятор для него на ассемблере. И так много итераций это развивалось. А как написать компилятор языка на самом языке? Сначала на языке более низкого уровня пишем компилятор для подмножества языка, необходимого для реализации компилятора, потом дописываем на этом подмножестве весь язык.

Comment: Впрочем, как в предположении в самом вопросе и написано... От простого к сложному. Один уровень абстракции опирается на другой.

Comment: добавлю только, что это называется bootstrap и для многих компиляторов это очень важный момент, когда они вначале написаны на с/с++, а потом переписываются на самом себе.

Comment: большое спасибо